# News feed website

Tags: rss, feed, feedly

I want to have a news aggregator website like Feedly with curated content from architecture and design community (and with thumbnails). I choose the news and the readers read it - no users login. I could do it manually, but I want it to be automated. Also, most of those webs don't have their own rss. What software would you recommend instead of making a custom made code by the developer?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to create/start a News Feed website, then the best CMS would be Wordpress, as it allows you do almost everything which you stated above.
For instance, I just googled this site, and it's an answer to your question: http://www.virtuefy.com

It does not require any logins, and users can read stories/articles and can comment.

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: this is promotion of an external website/product